# Visual Basic 2010 - Send ASCII over Serial port not the same as Displayed in programm

Tags: vb.net, serial-port

I want to send the ASCII code 241 which is a "ñ" over the serial port. However at the other end of the Port I always get a "?" instead of an "ñ".
Why is the character changed?

```
MessageBox.Show(Chr(241))          'gives "ñ"
SerialPort1.Write(Chr(241))        'gives "?"
```

Comment: What are your com port settings?

Comment: 241 is not an ASCII code, they stop at 127.  So the character gets turned into the ASCII version of "Qué¿", the ? character.  Read/write bytes, not characters.  Or change the SerialPort.Encoding property.

Comment: there is extended ascii, but your character would be 164, not 241.  http://www.asciitable.com/    You have to find out what your device supports.

Comment: com Port Settings: SerialPort1.Parity = IO.Ports.Parity.None
                SerialPort1.StopBits = IO.Ports.StopBits.One
                SerialPort1.DataBits = 8            'Open our serial port
                SerialPort1.ReadTimeout = 200
                SerialPort1.ReadBufferSize = 10000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i found the Problem I just added now:
SerialPort1.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1252)
and it works.

Thx anyway for all the help

Answer (score 0):

there is extended ascii, but your character would be 164, not 241.  http://www.asciitable.com/    You have to find out what your device supports.

> char 241:  http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/extended-ascii-code/plus-minus-sign-ascii-code-241.html
>
> char 164:  http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/extended-ascii-code/spanish-enye-lowercase-letter-n-tilde-enie-ascii-code-164.html

Comment: ok thx why are there so many versions of ASCII codes? I willt ry to use the 164 and will report back

Comment: ok didn't work still get a "?". It looks like it just can send up to "~" then every other code is just a "?". Why I don't have access to teh Extended ASCII characters

Comment: check the device's capabilities.  Does it offer support for extended ascii?

Comment: and there are multiple versions of ascii because it evolved as needs and available technology evolved.

Comment: why does it need those codes to transmit data?  What kind of device is this?  I can understand if your data has that value, but not why you need that specific character to transmit.  You typically use the non-printable characters from 00 to 31 for that kind of stuff.

Comment: the device is an EFKA Control Systems. The serial protocol works like this... Here is the soruce code of a small working programm: http://rcm.ch/SourceCode/Source%20V3.0.zip  I need to adapt this to visual basic. The important part is in the Unit_main.cpp in the SendString section maybee this helps you...

Comment: have you tried writing `$A4`?  A4 is hex for 164, the n with tilde.  Looking through some instructional docs I found where values are passed  in this way.  If not, please link to the manual for your specific component.  I have not looked at your linked code.

Comment: hm didn't work I do get a "?". Here is the "manual" thats all I got.. http://www.rcm.ch/Protokoll_RS232_USB.xls

Comment: ok I found the soultion: SerialPort1.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1252) thx anyway for all your help